# Unity Error on m1 mac : " Failed to read key from keystore: invalid keystore format"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity  I installed the latest unity hub and unity (which are not apple silicon optimized). I then installed the android SDK through unity editor itself and tried to run a sample 3d project as it is.

It keeps showing error : `" Failed to read key from keystore: invalid keystore format : /Users/anshsachdeva/.android/debug.keystore"`

Does anyone know about this? I am not even trying to generate a signed apk! found many questions for Release build issues but all i am trying is to create a debug build.

Comment: Changing Gradle JDK verison helped me try this -> [View][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76000947/13651898

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I believe the issue is with how unity creates an environment for its projects. when I installed the Android SDK via the editor, instead of using my current JDK/android studio tools/NDK/gradle, it installed a fresh copy of all these tools. However, in settings, I found that the Keystore path was still `/Users/anshsachdeva/"`.

I am guessing that Android SDK needs to validate a Keystore every time it generates a build. And since the SDK of my "Android Studio" created that Keystore, the SDK from "Unity Editor" was not finding it valid.

I simply deleted the debug Keystore there and voila! the unity app gets created and runs successfully

Kinda awkward but every time I switch my software, I will have to repeat this process.

---

**Update** : Following info is suggested by a stack overflow user (name showing as anonymous in edit request) . I cannot verify this right now, but approving it as it might be useful :

> Kinda awkward but every time I switch my software, I will have to repeat this process.

With regards to this sentence, one can create their own debug keystore in Unity and do not need to delete it in .android folder.
You need to click on Player setting:
Under Player, click on Publishing Settings, then click on Keystore Manager. Fill all the required info and save it anywhere you want. For the next build, the generated debug keystore will be used.

Comment: After 4 days of debugging! this was my savior! thanks!